# Encoding HTML within XML

Tags: html, xml, encoding

I have a big XML file which contains some HTML

```
<Orchard>
  <Recipe>
    <Name>Generated by Orchard.ImportExport</Name>
    <Author>admin</Author>
  </Recipe>
  <Data>
    <BodyPart Text="<p>My HTML</p><p align ="center">blah blah</p>"/>
  </Data>
</Orchard>
```

I want to encode the HTML, but leave the XML unencoded.
I've given regular expressions a shot but couldn't come up with a solution.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Use a CDATA section instead if you have a chance to change your XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution (not the most nicest way I know but it worked):
I moved the HTML into a CDATA as Brett Zamir suggested.
I then created a small program to parse the XML, find all the BodyPart items, and escape the HTML inside. Then moved the escaped HTML into the Text attribute, and deleted the inner text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple hand-coded solution:

```
<Orchard>
  <Recipe>
    <Name>Generated by Orchard.ImportExport</Name>
    <Author>admin</Author>
  </Recipe>
  <Data>
    <BodyPart><Text><![CDATA[<p>My HTML</p><p align ="center">blah blah</p>]]></Text></BodyPart>
  </Data>
</Orchard>
```

...but bear in mind that if the text "]]>" is present in the HTML, it will need to be escaped.

If you can't modify the structure of the file, use the DOM to find the attribute, and you should only need to escape the ampersand (with `&amp;`) and the encapsulating quote (the double quote in your case--`&quot;`).

You might indicate what server-side language you are using and whether you can change the XML.

Comment: I'm passing the XML into Orchard to import some blog entries. Unfortunately Orchard doesn't like the CDATA section. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy the BodyPartDriver to your own project and override the Import and Export methods. This way you can encrypt/encode do whatever you want. It will run after the Import/Export from the usual BodyPartDriver.

```
[UsedImplicitly]
public class BodyPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<BodyPart>
{
    protected override void Importing( BodyPart part, ImportContentContext context )
    {
       //Do your decoding here
        var importedText = context.Attribute( part.PartDefinition.Name, "Text" );
        if ( importedText != null )
        {
            part.Text = importedText;
        }
    }

    protected override void Exporting( BodyPart part, ExportContentContext context )
    {
        //Do your encoding here
        context.Element( part.PartDefinition.Name ).SetAttributeValue( "Text", part.Text );
    }
}
```